# damned thing will do me

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

While I’m reading *The Martian*,

> I may as well yell toward Earth for all the good **that damned thing will do me**.

What is the meaning of “damned things will do me” here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take it a bit at a time.

To say that something will **do me good** means that it will benefit me in some way.

To say that something will **do me no good** means that it will not benefit me in any way.

The word **damned** (like **bloody** and lots of similar expressions) is an expletive whose proper meaning is **consigned to hell(fire)**.

But like **bugger** and **bastard** and a good many other expletives, it has lost most of the force it once had. It's really just another way of saying **useless**.

So the text is saying that the object concerned - presumably some kind of communications device - is as useless as simply yelling aloud in the direction of earth. It will not do the speaker any good. It won't be of assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This sentence extends the expression “...for all the good it will do”, meaning that doing another useless thing will be just as effective as the first thing.

“I may as well yell toward Earth for all the good that [damned thing] will do [me].”

Is this talking about a low-power radio? That wouldn’t be able to be heard from Earth, so he’d be just as well served by yelling in Earth’s general direction than trying the radio - that is, none.